# ASP.NET C# Only allow bool set to true in 1 column

Tags: c#

I am just trying to understand how I can achieve this logically and what I would need to write in my code.

I have an application that allows me to send off user applications to universities and the university will update the application with either accept or reject. If the user has been accepted, the user can then choose to accept the offer by updating the application and selecting the firm tickbox. I only want it so that each user can only have one firm application and any other attempts at selecting a firm application will fail as the user should only be able to have 1 firm.

The code below is needing to check all the applications from the user to see if the offer is "P" and then needs to say if its the only firm then allow the tickbox to be checked.

Here is some code i've started but unsure how to carry on.

```
        public ActionResult UpdateApplication(Application application, int applicationId)
    {
        User test = userService.GetUserFromApplications(application);
        IList<Application> test2 = userService.GetApplications(test.UserId);

        if (application.Firm == true && application.Offer == "U")
        foreach (var item in test2)
        {

        }

        //if (application.Firm == true)
        //try
        //{
        //        applicationService.UpdateApplication(application, applicationId);
        //        return RedirectToAction("GetUsers", "User");
        //}
        //catch
        //{
        //    return View();
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Firm 1 has already been firmed')</script>");
        //}



    }
```

This part is relating to the cshtml

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Offer, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Offer, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Offer, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Firm, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Firm)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Firm, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: So one the user has a firm application they can’t have another? If you’re not worried by two firm applications at exactly the same time, then just make the operation fail if there’s already one present. If you are concerned that the _first_ application must succeed, then you’ll probably need a database lock.

Comment: Yes it can only have 1 firm offer per user. Would i not need a for loop to check the user has not already checked another firm on another application? I'm not quite sure how to write this

Comment: so you want to disable something in the web UI? Please show the razor code that renders the page and highlight the control you want disabled

Comment: This is the code from my cshtml relating to the offer and firm. I don't think i need to disable something, unless once something has been firmed then i cannot unfirm it. However if someone was to try firm another application when one is firmed then it should give them a popup message.

Comment: I've never dealt with ASP but I would suggest looking for controls with "Radio" in their name.